# Calling collection data on helper

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

I'm trying to build a house rental website and implemented google maps markers for each listing. I have stored the lat,long of each house in the collection along with its title.

But I am not able to call {{olat}} on the helper side as I am able to on the view template to act as placeholder for each. How can I call collection data inside the helper give below.

```
Template.listing.rendered = function() {
    var tmpl = this;

    VazcoMaps.init({}, function() {

        tmpl.mapEngine = VazcoMaps.gMaps();

        tmpl.newMap2.addMarker({
            lat: 28.6508, //replace this with lat,long variable stored in collection
            lng: 77.3152, //for each listing
            zoom: 11
            icon: '/images/mark.png',
            draggable: false
        });

    });

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your `olat` value is available on your template's [data context](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/), and you want to retrieve it in your `onRendered` hook. Seems a good place to call [`Template.currentData()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_currentdata):

```
Template.listing.onRendered(function () {
  var tmpl = this;
  var context = Template.currentData();

  VazcoMaps.init({}, function() {
    tmpl.mapEngine = VazcoMaps.gMaps();

    tmpl.newMap2.addMarker({
      lat: context.olat,
      lng: context.olong,
      zoom: 11,
      icon: '/images/mark.png',
      draggable: false
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Wow Mate, that was quick. Trying it out. Thanks a ton!